# Bootstrap navbar social media icon mobile version

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I built a navigation panel using bootstrap. I have a problem with the mobile version of my website.

[Here is a sample on codepen](https://codepen.io/pawe-dejda/pen/REqWMO).

I tried to rebuild it, but the project breaks down all the time.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top font">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
      </button>
      <a href="#up" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:100px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#about">O MNIE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">JAK PRACUJEMY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PROJEKTY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">KONTAKT</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook mr-1"></i></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a> </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The easiest way for me to explain the effect is by sending you photos.

before:

[image: 1]

---

after

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: so you need `after` photos effect in your code ?

Comment: you cant use `bootstrap 3.3.7 CSS` and `bootstrap 4.0 JS` in same time and same project, it creates problem in future

Comment: @NishargShah Yes! I want social icons to be visible in the mobile version and all the rest hidden in the menu. Full version look like this https://imgur.com/RHVjIlX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a second pair of social media icons and then manually hide elements at certain widths with the @media rule. That would make it look like they've moved when all you really did was hide one of them.

#### This is how you do it:

Add this to the html right after your navbar-brand:

```
<div class="collapse-social-icons">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
</div>
```

and the class **collapse-social-icons-dropdown** to the icons that you want to hide on small screens. Like this:

```
<li class="nav-item collapse-social-icons-dropdown"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook mr-1"></i></a></li>
```

Then I added this to the css:

```
/* This is to float the social incons to the right */
.collapse-social-icons {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* This is to add the same hover-effect as the other menu items */
.collapse-social-icons a:hover {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

/* This is to hide the "new" set of icons on big screens */
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .collapse-social-icons {
    display:none !important;
  } 
}

/* This is to hide the "old" set of icons on small screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .collapse-social-icons-dropdown {
    display:none !important;
  } 
}
```

The @media rule in the css applies when the width of the page is smaller than 767px. You can modify that anyway you want and you can allso specify a max-width if you want to.

Check it out here https://codepen.io/wenzzzel/pen/jXQVNv

Comment: It's a great idea! e.g. the facebook icon is active across the width and you make a line between facebook and instagram. Something is still wrong. I don't know how to modify it correctly.

Comment: I've updated my comment and the code-snipped aswell. Check it out!

Comment: Is it possible for the icons to be closer to the pull-down menu button? Now they are very close to the logo. 
Can I make the menu no longer show social media icons? I mean the mobile version of the menu extension.
That's how I know I'm picky, but pedantic. You helped me a lot.

Comment: Didnt have time to look at the position of the icons as of now, but I did add a @media rule for the max width to remove the social media buttons inside the dropdown and updated the codepen once again. Also I added the newly created css class collapse-social-icons-dropdown to the old icons in the html part.

Comment: You are amazing! If only you have a moment to see the position, I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: I've looked into it and added "position: relative" and "float: right" to the new icons on small screens. I've allso added some comments to the css to further explain what it does. Check out the codepen! :)

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! Everything works perfectly! 

You've noticed a problem with scaling the navigation bar from 768 to 991 width px?

Comment: You can probably fix that with the @media rule.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could add your social icons inside another div that is adjacent to the mobile button and utilize the d-none d-md-block to display them in mobile and hide them in larger views. You will also need to update your css to use Bootstrap 4's css lib.

```
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">      
    <div class="d-block d-md-none">
    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook mr-1"></i></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
    </button>
    <a href="#up" class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:100px;">
    </a>
</div>
```

And then in your regular nav:

```
    <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook mr-1"></i></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
```